# Erlang; form massive repeating integer

Tags: erlang

In Erlang, is there a way to form a massive repeating integer without lists?

I wrote:

```
{I, _} = string:to_integer(lists:concat([9 || _ <- lists:seq(1,trunc(math:pow(10,2)))])), I.
```

which forms a list of 100 9s and then the integer 999.... (100 9s). However, this fails if I want to, say, form a list the number that is one billion 9s:

```
{I, _} = string:to_integer(lists:concat([9 || _ <- lists:seq(1,trunc(math:pow(10,9)))])), I.
```

(never finishes).

List wise, the memory footprint of the list of 1 billion integers should be about 4GB, so shouldn't be a memory issue to hold the single massive int (though I am not sure how arbitrary precision integers is achieved in Erlang).

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @SteveVinoski I realized later that this was the wrong way to solve my problem, but that said, I still wanted to know how to do what I was trying to do. So I no longer have a good reason for this beyond "curiosity"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really create such a long list and then try to convert it to integer. List in Erlang is a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data_structure#Linked_lists) with each element containing the value and an address to the next element. For 64-bit system that would mean 16 bytes per element:

- 8 bytes for the address
- 1 word / 8 bytes for [small integer](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html)

Word size on 64-bit system:

```
7> erlang:system_info(wordsize).
8
```

So, constructing a list with 1.0e9 elements would require 1.6e10 bytes or 15 Gb:

```
13> 1.6e10 / (1024*1024*1024).
14.901161193847656
```

That's very likely beyond what a single process can allocate on most systems.

The only way is to apply some sort of mathematical formula to create such a number algorithmically. A naive implementation would simply multiply by 10 and add the number multiple times:

```
-module(bigint).

-export([make/2]).

make(N, A) -> make(N, A, N).

make(_N, 1, R) -> R;
make(N, A, R) -> make(N, A-1, R*10+N).
```

Result:

```
2> bigint:make(3, 5).
33333
```

But it's slowing down exponentially with the amount of numbers so anything beyond a few hundred thousand numbers is probably too computationally expensive to calculate.

You could also try to generate a binary instead of a list since binaries are [implemented on consecutive bytes](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#id67309) in segments of memory, e.g.:

```
-module(bigint).

-export([make/2]).

make(N, A) ->
    Bin = integer_to_binary(N),
    make(Bin, A, Bin).

make(_B, 1, R) -> binary_to_integer(R);
make(B, A, R) -> make(B, A-1, <<R/binary, B/binary>>).
```

But computationally this will be similar to the previous solution - a big binary can be constructed very quickly but later converting it to an integer is computationally expensive.

You may try to ask a question about an algorithm to create a big number algorithmically with the minimal amount of steps or the [Mathematic SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and then ask about a specific implementation of such algorithm here.

Answer (score 1):

Using an intermediary list is not useful, a bitstring is not directly convert into an integer so I don't think it is useful either, so the best solution is to use directly big nums.
Let say you want create an integer which is represented in decimal notation by the repetition of N times of a Pattern of width Width:

with `N = 3`, `Pattern = 52`, `Width = 4`, the expected result is `5200520052`

The first simple implementation, calculating the result by shifting and add the Pattern N times works but is very inefficient for big N. Here is an implementation (note that to measure the performance I have avoided to print the result, because otherwise the shell will transform the integer in iolist):

```
-module (pattern).

-export ([simple/3,perf/4]).

simple(N,Pattern,Width) when is_integer(N), N > 0 ->
    simple(N,Pattern,shift(1,Width),0).

simple(0,_,_,R) -> R;
simple(X,P,Shift,R) -> simple(X-1,P,Shift,R*Shift+P).


shift(X,0) -> X;
shift(X,N) -> shift(10*X,N-1).

perf(Type,N,P,S) ->
    {T,_} = timer:tc(?MODULE,Type,[N,P,S]),
    T.
```

with this you get the result:

```
1> pattern:simple(7,52,3).
52052052052052052052
2> pattern:simple(7,52,2).
52525252525252
3> pattern:perf(simple,1000,5,1).    
0
4> pattern:perf(simple,10000,5,1).
63000
5> pattern:perf(simple,100000,5,1).
1810000
6> pattern:perf(simple,1000000,5,1).
309522533
```

The time are very long (5 minutes for 1000000) and increasing exponentially.

The idea to reduce this is to decrease exponentially the number of operation to do. This smarter version is using a pattern wich is doubled in width at each iteration, and is concatenated at the current result when needed (I have use a decomposition of N in power of 2):

```
-module (pattern).

-export ([simple/3,smarter/3,perf/4]).

simple(N,Pattern,Width) when is_integer(N), N > 0 ->
    simple(N,Pattern,shift(1,Width),0).

simple(0,_,_,R) -> R;
simple(X,P,Shift,R) -> simple(X-1,P,Shift,R*Shift+P).


shift(X,0) -> X;
shift(X,N) -> shift(10*X,N-1).

perf(Type,N,P,S) ->
    {T,_} = timer:tc(?MODULE,Type,[N,P,S]),
    T.

smarter(1,Pattern,_Width) -> Pattern;
smarter(N,Pattern,Width) when is_integer(N), N > 0 ->
    smarter(N,Pattern,shift(1,Width),0).

smarter(1,Pattern,Shift,R) -> 
    R * Shift + Pattern;
smarter(X,Pattern,Shift,R) when (X rem 2) == 0 -> 
    smarter(X div 2, Shift * Pattern + Pattern, Shift * Shift, R);
smarter(X,Pattern,Shift,R) -> 
    smarter(X div 2, Shift * Pattern + Pattern, Shift * Shift, R * Shift + Pattern).
```

The results are much better: 5 seconds for 1000000, still increasing in n*n, due to the multiplications.

```
1> pattern:smarter(7,52,4).          
52005200520052005200520052
2> pattern:smarter(7,9,1). 
9999999
3> pattern:perf(smarter,1000,5,1).
0
4> pattern:perf(smarter,10000,5,1).
0
5> pattern:perf(smarter,100000,5,1).
125000
6> pattern:perf(smarter,500000,5,1). 
1279007
7> pattern:perf(smarter,1000000,5,1).
5117000
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, it's certainly smarter than my (naive) example but I didn't want to make it smarter on purpose. I only wanted to give some examples how it could be done, because such algorithm could be implemented in hundreds of ways. Maybe Erlang VM would convert a huge binary composed of nines more quickly than by multiplying huge numbers by huge numbers? Maybe there is a specific mathematical algorithm that's even quicker than your smarter implementation? Maybe the easier way is to construct a .erl file where the big number is already compiled to an integer with erlc?

Comment: I agree, it is why it is not named "smartest"  :o)